# Ruby, Neography Gem: Finding nodes via Key/value Pair

Tags: ruby, macos, neo4j

I am using [Neography](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography). I created an index, and have a node with this property:

[image: neo4j web admin]

[image]

But this code returns `nil`:

```
@neo.find_node_index("lucene","id_str", "5426722")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The format is: `@neo.get_node_index(index, key, value)`

The name of your index happens to be the same name as your key (I am assuming since we can see the index name, but not the key that was used).

```
@neo.get_node_index("id_str","id_str", "5426722")
```

You can find some examples on how to do it in the [neography GitHub repository](https://github.com/maxdemarzi/neography/blob/master/spec/integration/rest_index_spec.rb).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **get_node_index** instead. It looks like it should have the same functionality for the values you are supplying, since you aren't passing a query?

Comment: Same nil output. I think I'm **not** inputting the right parameters in. I'm basically trying to check if the node already exists, before I put in data: If it exists, append data to node. If it doesn't exist create new node. So above is to search for node's existence.